# Moq for the Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, moq, dapper

I have a controller. From where I am calling(DI of BLL) to the Business Logic layer(BLL) . From BLL I am calling the Data access layer(DAL) through one more interface.

DAL layer constructor is injected with the DBContext instance( there is no Interface injected here).

So by using MOQ we can test controller , BLL & intermediated layer. But how to test the DLL layer?

```
    public class DAL():IDAL
    {
        private DBEntities entity;

        public DAL(DBEntities DB)
        {
            entity = DB;
        }

        public list<string> ABC()
        {
            var a = SqlMapper.Query<class>(entity.Database.Connection, "",param,commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
            return a;
        }
    }
```

Basically my query how to & what to mock here? Here we implement the IDAL, but we don't inject it here.

Comment: It's actually Unit of Work pattern. In the constructor we have injected the Entity framework Object to avoid multiple object creation. in public ABC()
you can see the implementation . AS we are using it to pass the Dbcontext connection object in the Dapper method.

Comment: Lets put my question straight forward. If  I have to moq a method where I do inject DB entity, how to do?

Comment: Exactly , I tried in that way, but here the blocker is when the Mock data I am passing from the unit testing , method hits to the real database, where as I need to get it from mocked.

Comment: I have edited the method hope its clear.

Comment: Here the major blocker is there is no Dependency injection happening with any Interface. So we m unable to Mock the layer to test any method.

Answer (score 1):

The question is still not 100% clear to me but I try to give an answer.

There is not need to mock `DBEntities`. If you want to make sure your queries return the correct result then test it with a well known, prefilled database which you only use for your tests.

If you want to test your business logic and need to mock your data access layer, then mocking is helpfull! So create an Interface with your methods:

```
public interface IDAL
{
    List<string> ABC();
}
```

In your unit test you can mock the interface with:

```
var dataAccessMock = new Mock<IDAL>();
dataAccessMock.Setup(x => x.ABC()).Returns(new List<string> {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI" });
// get an IDAL instance which you can inject / use
var mockedInstance = dataAccessMock.Object;
// get the mocked list
var list = mockedInstance.ABC();
```

Comment: So in this case, its not going to hit the Real  ABC() method. its will just bypass the code. Then its not going to workout right?

We suppose to mock the dependency & to pass to the method.

Comment: But this is the Idea. Why else would you have a DataAccessLayer then? If you want to mock your `DBEntities` what do you expect to return its `Database.Connection` property? You would also have to mock your `SqlMapper.Query<>()` method and what is the benefit of that?

Comment: Actually this is my question here. If we can't mock Dbentites, then we can't give a mock Connection here. In this case I tried to mock SQlmapper.Query<>(), but its throwing error, 1)as SQLMapper is a static class, 2) if somehow forcefully I write the Query<>, its saying Query not found in SQlMapper.

Advantage is if our Unit test hits the real method with Mock object then we will get better code coverage.

Comment: can I get any help here?

Comment: I don't see the benefit. Your function ABC is very simple. It returns data from the Database. To test this, you want to mock all it's objects, that allow communicating with the database. I cannot see any valuable test in that. 
Here I'd rather write integration-tests with a real database and check if the data its returns is in the expected form. And don't make yourself a slave to code coverage metrics.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock and create in constructor of test class for DAL instance of InMemoryDb which will be just an empty schema of your db, than propage it with some data needed for testing and than check your queries. That's how I do it.

```
    public class SomeTests : IDisposable
{
        public SomeTests()
        {
            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                .Options;

            _dbContext = new MyContext(options);
            _dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            _dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();

            // you can provide some more settings here
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _dbContext?.Dispose();
        }
}
```